# Roll mean value theorem prove equation

Tags: rolles-theorem

Assume that $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differential in $(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, prove that there exists a $\xi\in(a,b)$, s.t $f'(\xi)=f(\xi)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I get an anwser that let $F(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$, then $F(b)=0,F(a)=0$,so we just apply the Roll theorem to complete this proof.But I don't know how I get $F(x)$?

Comment: When you come across such equalities it's always a good practice to multiply with something that is always nonzero in order to make the expression equal the derivative of some function. The exponential function  $e^{\pm x}$ is a very good candidate since it is always positive and is ($\pm$) the derivative of itself.

Comment: @WangAliber FYI, your question is basically [Prove there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $f(\xi)=f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3194395/602049) with $n = 0$. However, since that other problem involves a more general, and likely harder to solve, problem than yours, I'm not considering it to be a duplicate. Nonetheless, although I couldn't offhand find any, I suspect some do exist. Regardless, I hope you find my linked post to be of some help. Good luck with solving your problem.

Comment: I assume you mean "s.t. $f'(\xi) = 0$", since as stated you are trying to prove something false.

Comment: Thanks for your help!